# inserting double dimensional array into ms-access dynamically in java

Tags: database, arrays, ms-access, 2d

i want to insert double dimensional array into ms-access dynamically in java ..

here is my code..

```
    try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver " +
        "(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Documents and Settings\\ANIL KUMAR\\Desktop\\hyperdata.mdb";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

if i have a string array with two columns:

```
String[][] a = new String[10][2];
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sap_details VALUES (?,?)");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pst.setString(1, a[i][0]);
    pst.setString(2, a[i][1]);
    pst.addBatch();
}
pst.executeBatch();
```

what if have a have string array with n columns and n rows?
how to insert string array a[n][n]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an inner for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++) {
     System.out.print(a[i][j]);
  }
}
```

You can also use enhanced loop as below

```
for (String[] array : a) {  
  for (String s : array) {  
    System.out.println(s);  
   }  
}
```